# C++ variadic macro to variadic function

Tags: c++, macros, variadic-functions

Implementing an assertion macro I stumbled upon a problem on Xcode clang.

I use the following code:

```
void Log(LogLevel logLevel, const std::string& message);

std::string FormatString(const char* format, ...);

#define LOG(Level, Format, ...)                                     \
{                                                                   \
    std::string _ac_err_str_ = FormatString(Format, ##__VA_ARGS__); \
    Log(Level, _ac_err_str_);                                       \
}

#define checkf(expr, Format, ...)   { if(!(expr)) { LOG(LL_ErrorMessage, TXT("Log in file ") __FILE__ TXT(" at line %d: ") TXT(#expr) TXT(". ") Format, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__); } }
```

Everything works fine with MSVC but on Clang I get the following error: `Expected expression`

I've tracked down the problem on this line:

```
std::string _ac_err_str_ = FormatString(Format, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

More specifically the problem is on the `##__VA_ARGS__` part because if I remove it everything compiles.

Also, if I pass a third parameter to the macro it compiles, e.g.:

```
checkf(false, "Error message");       // Won't compile
checkf(false, "Error %s", "message"); // Will compile
```

It seems like there's an error on passing the macro's variadic arguments to `FormatString`, but I can't find out the reason or how to fix this.

Comment: `##__VA_ARGS__` isn't standard. Don't expect it to work portably. It also doesn't look like there's any particular reason to use a macro over a variadic template for `LOG`.

Comment: Please, do yourself a favor and learn about variadic templates

Comment: I DO know about variadic templates. Anyway, found out how to solve this since I've used the macro on a lot of points inside my code and don't want to change them.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently on Clang I need to change my `checkf` macro like this

```
#define checkf(expr, Format, ...)   { if(!(expr)) { LOG(LL_ErrorMessage, TXT("Log in file ") __FILE__ TXT(" at line %d: ") TXT(#expr) TXT(". ") Format, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__); } }
```

Notice that I've used `##__VA_ARGS__` instead of just `__VA_ARGS__`.

It compiles with both MSVC and Clang as well.